# How to determine if software on many client machines is up to date?

Tags: vulnerability, client-side, software

I have to take care of 200+ client machines (mainly Windows 8,8.1, 10) in an organization. There are many apps installed: web browsers, Java, Flash & many more.
Are there any tools/techniques to check which machines have outdated software, for example vulnerable Java, and to get regular reports of the machines that needs update?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't do product recommendations here. But yes, there are many security scanners that will look around your network for vulnerabilities, and many sysadmin tools that will manage software versions across a fleet of computers; good practice would be to use both.

Comment: Try Secunia CSI or a Nessus credentialed scan

Comment: There are many, many products for this very purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are several classes of tools that can do this.

You may want to look at using a vulnerability scanner that can run authenticated scans where it logs in and can scan the local filesystems & configurations rather than just scanning the services listening on the IP addresses on the network.

Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) tools can gather most of the same information but also help you with making the updates to these systems.

You may find that the best solution for your environment is to use multiple types of tools too.

Answer (score 1):

To produce report and for better control of such large set of organisation windows machines, I would write a script querying installed software and version interfacing directly with [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx)

E.g. Powershell can retrieve the list of installed applications in a remote computer with the line:
`Get-WmiObject win32_Product -ComputerName`...`|Sort Vendor,Name`

See [win32_Product](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx)